# how to use a defined class in ckeditor?

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor

CKEditor 4.6.0

I would like to use CKEditor, here is the CodePen where I show the code

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RQBMzp

In my code, I have defined `allowedContent` to `true` and `extraAllowedContent`.

I have defined a style for the 'CreateDiv' button (but I don't know why we can't see the CreateDiv button).

So, I have simulated a div with a class in the CKEditor, just read the code.

Why the class is not used? if I try with a style tag, there is no issue

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CKEditor creates an iframe, so your CSS is not used since it is applied in the host page (it would work however if you were using [Div Editing Area](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/divarea) add-on, which uses `div` instead of `iframe`). Use one of the following solutions:

- Edit `contents.css` in CKEditor folder and insert your CSS rules (it is overwritten however on CKEditor update).
- Create another CSS file, let's say `mystyles.css`, insert your CSS rules and in `config.js` insert:

  `config.contentsCss = [CKEDITOR.getUrl('contents.css'), CKEDITOR.getUrl('mystyles.css')];`
- For a quick solution, insert the following line before your `CKEditor.replace` command to be applied for a specific page:

  `CKEDITOR.addCss('.collapse { background-color: tan; }');`

See here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NyBzaq

Comment: thank you so much, I didn't know that ckeditor uses an iframe. But about the example, in the documentation, it's indicated to use allowedContent etc...

Comment: By using `allowedContent: true` (or even better `extraAllowedContent: 'div(collapse)'`) you tell CKEditor to keep the `class` attributes of `div` in source code and not strip it. However, you will not see anything different visibly, for the reasons I explained.

Comment: thank you, now, I can include it with django-ckeditor.